# Simple audio recording software

Tags: audio, recording

There are lot of questions regarding audio recording software on this forum, but I didn't find what I need. I am practicing speaking a foreign language, and I want to hear  how I speak. I do not want to save my recordings. Basically I want an application with  a record button and play button, such that as soon as I press record the previous recording gets erased and a new one starts. Quick Time works great, but it always offers to save an untitled file which is very annoying, and I don't find an option to turn that off.

Answer (score 1):

### [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net)

> Audacity® is free, open source, cross-platform software for recording and editing sounds.

You can click record, record the sound, stop and playback, then start again by clicking record. You can play only the latest recording by choosing to 'solo' the last selected track (which is the last track that you recorded to).